# NuxtJS - webpack. How to split vendors and app to separate css chunks?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

I am trying to configure nuxt.config.js so that vendor and all the other styles would be separated into vendors.css and app.css chunks. This is how my nuxt.config.js looks now:

```
  mode: 'universal',
  head: {
    title: process.env.npm_package_name || '',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      {
        hid: 'description',
        name: 'description',
        content: process.env.npm_package_description || ''
      }
    ],
    link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }]
  },
  loading: { color: '#fff' },
  css: [
    '@/assets/style/vendors.scss',
    '@/assets/style/app.scss'
  ],
  plugins: ['@/plugins/buefy'],
  buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/eslint-module'
  ],
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/style-resources'
  ],
  axios: {},
  build: {
    styleResources: {
      scss: './assets/style/utilities.scss'
    },
    extractCSS: true,
    extend(config, ctx) {}
  }
}
```